# Passing a Pinia Store as a Prop with Vue3 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am using Typescript, Pinia, and Vue3 and have a `MenuButton` component that I want to be able to pass a Pinia store that is used for the menu open state as well as the actions to show/hide. There are a couple different menus in the app, hence why I want to be able to pass them in, and they all use the same factory to define the stores. I'm trying to figure out how to get all of this to work with typescript.

```js
// nav.store.ts

import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useStorage } from "@vueuse/core";
import type { RemovableRef } from "@vueuse/core";

export interface MenuStore {
    isOpen: RemovableRef<boolean>,
    toggle(force?: boolean) : void,
    open(): void,
    close(): void,
}

interface State {
    isOpen: RemovableRef<boolean>;
}

function menuStoreFactory(id: string) {
    return defineStore(id, {
        state: () : State => ({
            isOpen: useStorage(`${id}-open`, false),
        }),

        actions: {
            toggle(force?: boolean) {
                this.isOpen = force != undefined ? force : !this.isOpen;
            },

            open() {
                this.isOpen = true;
            },

            close() {
                this.isOpen = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

export const useMainMenuStore = menuStoreFactory('mainMenu');

export const useMobileMenuStore = menuStoreFactory('mobileMenu');
```

```js
// setup script for the menu button component

import { MenuIcon, MenuLeftIcon } from "@/icons";
import type { MenuStore } from "@/modules/nav/nav.store";

interface Props {
    controller: MenuStore
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();
```

Then usage is pretty straight forward:

```html
<template>
    <MenuButton
        :controller="mainMenu"
    ></MenuButton>
</template>
<script setup lang=ts">
    const mainMenu = useMainMenuStore();
</script>
```

With that current interface I got an error that the props didn't match. After some research I turned the interface into the following, which fixed the usage error, but then threw an error in the `MenuButton` component that `toggle()` and `isOpen` are unresolved.

```js
export interface MenuStore extends PiniaCustomStateProperties<{
    isOpen: RemovableRef<boolean>,
    toggle(force?: boolean) : void,
    open(): void,
    close(): void,
}> {}
```

Another attempted tweak that got close was:

```js
export interface MenuStore extends Store<string, {
    isOpen: RemovableRef<boolean>,
    toggle(force?: boolean) : void,
    open(): void,
    close(): void,
}> {}
```

which resulted in this error on usage, but no error in the component

```
Type _StoreWithState<string, State, {}, {toggle(force?: boolean): void, close(): void, open(): void}> & UnwrapRef<State> & _StoreWithGetters<{}> & {toggle(force?: boolean): void, close(): void, open(): void} & PiniaCustomProperties<string, State, {}, {toggle(force?: boolean): void, close(): void, open(): void}> & PiniaCustomStateProperties<State> is not assignable to type MenuStore ...   Type PiniaCustomStateProperties<State> is not assignable to type MenuStore
```

Comment: Could you include the actual text of the error you mentioned at the end?

Comment: Doesn't really change your question, but is Pinia really necessary here? Couldn't you just use a plain composable?

Comment: Also, as far as I could make out, you have this single menu button component that is connected to a menu when used. Could you rather not simply use pass a prop for the open state and use events for the actions? They could be bound from the Pinia store or the object returned from a composable; although it would be more verbose, it would be a lot simpler and cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes have updated the question with the latest attempt and the error it gave. And there will be multiple uses of this component to operate different menus, hence it being abstracted to a component

Comment: I understand that there will be multiple uses. That is why I suggested the method I did. If the store was being passed to "random" components that happened to have control over the menu state, I would not have suggested that. However, as it is passed to single component (single in definition, not in use) that appears to exist solely for opening and closing menus, I believe a state prop and events are the best method.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes but then I'm writing the same handlers and props every time I try to use it, just with a different variable, and that's the kind of thing you abstract into a component

Comment: Components _do_ abstract things, and it would still be abstracting them in the case I described. However, I am suggesting a different _interface_ for the component.

Comment: What logic is contained in the menu button? A lot of this depends on how "dumb" it is.

Comment: IMO, calling `useMainMenuStore()` in each component is the much cleaner way compares to using props

Comment: Now that I've got that digression out of my system... :) As to the question itself, is the runtime error you got not because you are trying to bind a non-reactive variable to a prop? Also, could you not rather use the return type of `menuStoreFactory` instead of constructing a type yourself? Or is that considered a bad practice?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes it's the return type of `defineStore` that's in question, not the factory method. That's what it boils down to, how to properly type the store, but hopefully in a manner that doesn't hard tie it to the store, hence trying to use the interface.

Comment: Re my earlier comment about the non-reactive variable: scratch that, I think a store is a reactive object.

Comment: Sorry, got lost in the nesting there. I meant the return type of the function returned by `defineStore` (which is the actual store object). `type MenuStore = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof menuStoreFactory>>`. I do understand that the resulting type will be pretty complex, though.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I totally forgot about ReturnType! Thank you. If you make that comment an answer I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be mostly about the type/interface you need, so I'll answer that.

Instead of writing out a type yourself, you can simply use the type of the returned store.

You have a factory function that returns the return value of `defineStore`, which is itself a function that returns the store. Therefore, the store's type can be found using `typeof` to get the type of the factory function and then TypeScript's `ReturnType` helper to drill down through the return types.

The following should be all you need:

```js
export type MenuStore = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof menuStoreFactory>>
```

Breakdown:

```js
ReturnType<                 // C
  ReturnType<               // B
    typeof menuStoreFactory // A
  >
>
```

- **A:** Get the type of the factory function.
- **B:** Get the return type of the factory function, which is the return from `defineStore`. This is itself a function which returns the store.
- **C:** Get the return type of said function. This is the type of the store itself.